# Google Sheets Equation for Sequence: 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.1, etc

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm looking for a way to generate the following sequence:
1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, etc.
Where the max number after the decimal is specified by the value in another cell, so for example could be updated to:
1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2, 3.1, 3.2

I'd like to use the ARRAYFORMULA function so that it auto-populates for a specified number of rows.

I cannot figure out this out, any ideas? Must be Google Sheet and not Excel
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this formula where `A1` is the max number before the dot, and `B1` - after:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  ROUNDUP((SEQUENCE(A1*B1, 1, 1))/B1)&"."& 
  (MOD(SEQUENCE(A1*B1, 1, 0), B1) + 1)
)
```

Another option where you can specify the total number of rows (`C1`) and max number after the dot (`B1`):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  ROUNDUP((SEQUENCE(C1, 1, 1))/B1)&"."& 
  (MOD(SEQUENCE(C1, 1, 0), B1) + 1)
)
```

Comment: The second option worked perfectly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to the following formula.

```
=REDUCE("Max Decimal From Cell",SEQUENCE(5),LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,MAP(SEQUENCE(E2),LAMBDA(t,x&"."&t)))))
```

Here `SEQUENCE(5)` is number before decimal place.

[image]

Comment: This is so close! The sequencing part works perfectly but instead of specifying max number before decimal, is there a way to change and specify of total row count instead?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(rows,15,
       cycle,3,
       ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
         TOCOL(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(rows/cycle))&"."&SEQUENCE(1,cycle)),
         rows,1)))
```

We are creating the sequence by performing a cartesian product between the set of numbers before the decimal point and the set of numbers after it.

```cpp
TOCOL(SEQUENCE(5)&"."&SEQUENCE(1,3))
```

Then we are constraining the resulting array to the specified number of rows. (It's easy to see that if the cycle divides the number of rows, the whole resulting array is returned)